# Regex - match string between quotes but also what precedes it

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

If I have a file that I need to search through for every occurrence of this:

```
firstName="string"
```

I know how to match the string between the quotes, but I would like to know how to match the variations of what precedes it. Like:

```
firstName ="string"
firstName = "string"
```

So, basically, I need to get all the strings, but I encountered a problem when there are variations like that, with added spaces before or after =. I'm sure this is really simple, but I'm really bad at regex so I would appreciate your help. Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know about C# explicitely, however something like the following should work:

```
(\w+)\s*=\s*"(.*?)"
```

*`(\w+)`* matches a block of alphanumeric characters an creates a capturing group

*`\s*`* matches 0 or more spacing characters

*`=`* matches **=**

*`\s*`* matches 0 or more spacing characters

*`"(.*?)"`* matches *"anything"* and creates a capturing group over what's inside *""*

I guess you need to make sure the *global* flag is enabled to get all matches.